# BSOD when using Microsoft Teams with video (ntoskrnl.exe)

Tags: windows-10, bsod, microsoft-teams

There seems to be some issue with Teams under Windows 10. I am on new Surface Book 3 and I have had 5 BSOD's all during a video call on teams. Apparently, there are quite few complaints for BSOD with Teams on the internet as well with no solutions.

I seeking help to pinpoint why this is happening. Here is an image of where it appears:
[image]

Comment: It is likely the Video / Driver on your Surface Book.  I have used Teams with my own Windows 10 laptop (Intel integrated graphics).  Try from another computer if you can.

Comment: The only real way to determine the cause of a BSOD is to use WinDBG and analyze the dump